# Calendar event displays on "at a glance" but has been deleted

Tags: google-calendar

A few years ago I set up a recurring calendar event. All was good. I was reliably reminded of this event. Then I deleted that event. My "at a glance" still shows that event as "coming up soon". If I tap on that event, an error message is displayed indicating that the event could not be found. I do not get a notification when the event time is met. I have cleared the cache and memory for the Google Calendar app. I am running the latest OS and security update. The app is on its latest version. This problem has persisted for months.

Android 12

Pixel 3a

Google Calendar app

How do I fix this?

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/57753372/at-a-glance-widget-displays-previously-deleted-google-calendar-events?hl=en It took maybe ~10 minutes for the event currently being shown to go away. I also have a work profile on my device so had to clear that one separately.